# ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded") Python googlemaps

Tags: google-app-engine, flask

I am using Google app engine (v1.9.24) with flask (v0.10.1) and python (v2.7.5).

I'm trying to get the googlemaps (v2.2) API to work with my app.

I know the JSON returned is badly formatted but I don't why.

My code is below:

```
import googlemaps
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='API_KEY')
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('6b, oko awo, victoria island, lagos')
return geocode_result
```

This works perfectly, but returns a badly formatted JSON string (I confirmed this by running the same code on my local machine).

I used [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com) to validate the JSON it returned. And because of the badly fomatted JSON my flask app crashes and gives me a ValueError.
I don't know a way around this and I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the JSON. Actually,

```
gmaps.geocode('6b, oko awo, victoria island, lagos')
```

doesn't return JSON at all, it returns a list that holds the value of "result" as documented in [the google docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro), as you can see [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python/blob/master/googlemaps/geocoding.py) in the source code for googlemaps library.

What is actually returned is a list object filled with data. All the string values inside this list are unicode strings. That means they look like `u'hello'` instead of plain `"hello"` (note the double quotes) that json.loads() expects (I assume that is how you are trying to load the JSON).

This probably means that the problem you're trying to solve a non existing problem. You don't have to load the JSON, because it already is a python list object.

You can confirm by doing

```
json.loads(json.dumps(geocode_result))
```

it works fine, meaning there is no problem with the JSON structure.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It does seem to work well when i run the code from the python console, but it does not work when I run it from the dev server (That's when it gives the ValueError).

Comment: Need more information.  For instance are you still trying to use json validator.  Show the code where the error is.